# Check in Azure Functions if client is still connected to SignalR Service

Tags: c#, push-notification, signalr, azure-functions, visual-studio-app-center

I've created negotiate and send message functions in Azure Functions (similar to the samples below) to incorporate the SignalR Service. I'm setting `UserId` on the `SignalRMessage` by using a custom authentication mechanism.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-signalr-service?tabs=csharp

```
[FunctionName("negotiate")]
public static SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)]HttpRequest req, 
    [SignalRConnectionInfo
        (HubName = "chat", UserId = "{headers.x-ms-client-principal-id}")]
        SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
{
    // connectionInfo contains an access key token with a name identifier claim set to the authenticated user
    return connectionInfo;
}

[FunctionName("SendMessage")]
public static Task SendMessage(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]object message, 
    [SignalR(HubName = "chat")]IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages)
{
    return signalRMessages.AddAsync(
        new SignalRMessage 
        {
            // the message will only be sent to this user ID
            UserId = "userId1",
            Target = "newMessage",
            Arguments = new [] { message }
        });
}
```

I'd like to send a push notification if the client is no longer connected instead of adding a new object to the `IAsyncCollector`. I've also set up `AppCenter` push framework properly, but I'm facing an issue. Is there an easy way to find out which `UserId` is still connected to the hub? This way, I could decide to send a push. What is the recommended Microsoft guidance on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this feature: [Azure SignalR Service introduces Event Grid integration feature](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-signalr-service-introduces-event-grid-integration-feature/), where the *SignalR Service* emits two following event types:

```
Microsoft.SignalRService.ClientConnectionConnected

Microsoft.SignalRService.ClientConnectionDisconnected
```

More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-azure-signalr).